# Full Calendar multidate event display one day short

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using full calendar v4, and whenever I have a multi date event, it is displaying a day short (if `end:2020-06-15` it goes up to 2020-06-14)

I tried using `nextDayThreshold: '00:00:00',` but no luck. I can't add a time to these events as well because every event is a full day event. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: the other alternative to the answer below is simply to add 1 day to the end date of all your events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add time to your event start and end time

To read more about `nextDayThreshold` Please refer to this [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/nextDayThreshold):

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/furjmwsc/15/

**Try this**

```
$('#id').fullCalendar({
   events: [
   {
    title: 'Custom Event',
    start: '2020-06-14T00:00:00',
     end: '2020-06-15T23:59:00'
  },
 ]
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for this solution, it works but is there no other way to do it? It shows `12a` before the event title so it would be great if there was a way to remove that. Either way thanks a lot.

Comment: I was just about to comment the same thing. Glad all is working.